# .htaccess remove file type extension when specifically entered

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment my .htaccess file will accept links with a format of:
`website.com/file` (automatically adding the .php)
or even one with an incorrect extension like:
`website.com/file.foo` (removing the extension and replacing it with .php)

However, if the user types in the URL with the *correct* extension, for example:
`website.com/file.php`, the extension will not be hidden. This isn't very aesthetically pleasing, so I would like to remove it. All the methods I try, though, result in an infinite redirect loop.

How would I do this?
My current code is:

```
#If the URL does not exist, try removing the URL's file type
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9_/]+)$ /$1 [NC,R]

#If the URL does not exist, but the URL+.php exists, then append the .php extension to it
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/-]+)$ /$1.php [NC,L]

#If the URL does not exist, but the URL+.html exists, then append the .html extension to it
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_/-]+)$ /$1.html [NC,L]

#If the URL does not exist and it's got the .php extension, get rid of the .php extension
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first rule section as below

```
#If the URL does not exist, try removing the URL's file type
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([A-Za-z0-9_/]+)\.([A-Za-z0-9_/])(\?|\ ) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,R=301]
```

Comment: That still has the same problem as before, although now it won't accept extensions with anything other than the correct extension.